# Cocos Creator and TypeScript use enum as property

Tags: typescript, cocoscreator

the question is strictly with TypeScript. the issue I have works perfectly if I have JavaScript based Cocos project in Cocos Creator.

I have the following enum in file called enums.

```
export const enum CollisionType {
Static=    0,
Dynamic=   1,
Solid=     2,
SemiSolid= 3
}
```

in my game.ts file I have the following

```
import {CollisionType} from "./Enums";

export default class PlayerControl extends cc.Component {

@property (CollisionType)
collisionType:CollisionType = CollisionType.Static;
```

but unfortunately this does not work. I get a red line under CollisionType and the following error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof CollisionType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | boolean | Function | any[] | { type?: any; visible?: boolean | (() => boolean); displayName?: string; tooltip?: string; multiline?: boolean; readonly?: boolean; min?: number; max?: number; ... 7 more ...; animatable?: boolean; } | ValueType'.
```

If I don't set the @property to my variable it works fine but then this value cannot be edited in the Cocos Creator editor.

any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

try the following code

```js
@property ({type:Enum(CollisionType)})
private collisionType:CollisionType = CollisionType.Static;
```